# I want to use a transition for the moment when two icons switch with each other

Tags: css

I'm a beginner, i searched a lot for an answer on the internet but none of them managed to clarify why the transition doesn't work.
HTML:

```
<li><i class="material-icons menu-bar" id="menu-bar">menu</i></li>
<ul class="menu-bar-content hide" id="menu-bar-content">
```

This is my Js :

```
const menuBar = document.getElementById('menu-bar');
const menuBarContent = document.getElementById('menu-bar-content');
var menuOpen = false;
menuBar.addEventListener('click' , menuBarBtn)
function menuBarBtn() {
    if ( menuOpen == false) {
        menuBar.innerHTML = '<li><i class="material-icons undo-icon">undo</i></li>';
        menuBarContent.className = 'menu-bar-content';
        menuOpen = true;
    }
    else {
        menuBar.innerHTML = '<li><i class="material-icons menu-bar" id="menu-bar">menu</i></li>';
        menuBarContent.className = 'menu-bar-content hide'
        menuOpen = false;
    }
};
```

And this is my Css:

```
.menu-bar {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    color: white;
    margin: -1.45% 0.7%;
    font-size: 23px !important;
    transition: .4s;
}

.undo-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    color: #1ec7b9;
    margin: 0.9% 3%;
    transform: rotateZ(43.2deg);
    font-size: 14px !important;
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 70%;
    padding: 1.5px;
    transition: .4s;
}
```

**After the icons switch with each other, i wanted to do it with a transition effect. Thank you in advance!**

Comment: It seems that you are using some library for material design. It would be easier to help u if u provide working fiddle.

Comment: You are completely overwriting one li element with another. CSS transitions work on CSS properties. You need to keep both li elements within the DOM and transition something like opacity and the rotation. Do you want the menu element to be hidden when the undo one is shown, or is it just the undo one that you want to show/hide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition is not happening because the element is completely removed/replaced with another onclick.

It is CSS properties that transition and the browser thinks it's got a completely new element, not one that is to be transitioned in some way.

What we do is have both li elements in the document all the time, but one of them will be hidden. To do this gradually we can use opacity: 0 alongside the rotation in a new class which is called faded here.

On a click we don't replace the li elements but we set the one that has not been clicked to have class faded - it will rotate and end up invisible with opacity: 0 and we remove the class faded from the other li element so it will rotate back to normal and with normal opacity.

Javascript has a handy function, toggle, for adding and removing a class so we don't have to remember which element is hidden and which is in view - having or not having class faded is enough.

Here is the snippet. Note, the body has been given a background-color just so we can see the white menu and the white border. Also I do not have access to whatever icons you are using so the i elements are replaced with spans just for this demo.

```js
const menuBar = document.getElementById('menu-bar');
const undoBar = document.getElementById('undo-bar');

menuBar.addEventListener('click' , menuBarBtn);
undoBar.addEventListener('click' , menuBarBtn);

function menuBarBtn() {
  menuBar.classList.toggle('faded');
  undoBar.classList.toggle('faded');
};
```

```css
body {
    background-color: gray; /* just for this test so we can see the white menu */
    }
.menu-bar {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    color: white;
    margin: -1.45% 0.7%;
    font-size: 23px !important;
    transition: .4s;
}
.undo-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    color: #1ec7b9;
    margin: 0.9% 3%;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 70%;
    padding: 1.5px;
    transition: .4s;
}
.faded { /* added this so when an element has class="faded" it cannot be seen and it is rotated */
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(43.2deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-bar-content" id="menu-bar-content" style="margin-top:30px;"> <!-- added just for this tesmargin t so we could see the white menu word in the snippet -->
  <li><span class="menu-bar" id="menu-bar">menu</span></li> <!-- remember to put back the <i icon calls in here in place of the spans -->
  <li><span class="menu-bar undo-icon faded" id="undo-bar">undo</span></li> <!-- ...and we start this off as faded so it isn't seen to begin with -->
</ul>
```